# Reading credit / debit card using NFC on Android

Tags: android, react-native, nfc

We have been using the following to parse credit card / debit card info.

```
implementation 'com.github.devnied.emvnfccard:library:3.0.1'
```

After getting the mTag using the code below:

```
final Tag mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

We were able to parse the information and retreive credit card information. We recently had to update compileSdkVersion from 30 to 33 and ever since the update the value we get for `mTag` ends up being `null`. This leads to a failure in any further processing that we want to do on `mTag`.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated in case anyone else ran into a similar issue.

I have tried playing around with the AndroidManifes file to include `TECH_DISCOVERED` in the intent-filter. Also tried palying around with the gradle version but on compileSdkVersion 33 it always returns null.

Comment: Did you check for (runtime) permissions ? In the last time Google/Android setup some new or additional ("granular") permissions.